# Overwatch downloaded from the store, what happens when I insert a game disc?

Tags: ps4, overwatch

I downloaded Overwatch on my PS4 during the last Free Weekend, and the game itself has not been moved or deleted.

Now that I have the Origins Edition on a Blu Ray, what is going to happen with the existing data? Specifically:

- Are the existing updates valid for the disc? Or I have to download the 20 GB update again? (I remember that some PS3 games had different updates and savedata for Digital and Physical copies)
- Is the game still launched from the disc?
- Is there any real difference between both copies/installs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Digital and Disc are two different versions. Save data work if you have the same region between digital and copy disc. Also, you can have 1 version of the game installed (digital OR disc copy).

From my experience, you will need to reinstall and download the data.

Comment: Bear in mind, "save data" for Overwatch is really only settings as your game inventory (skins, etc...) are stored on Blizzard's servers.

Comment: you are correct(my mistake not mention it). Everything is server side your personal settings etc and when you switch you just get those config's local.